# How do I pull the name of the user that posts to our page wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss, facebook-fql

I have looked through and couldn't find the answer on here...

We are doing a promotional giveaway and have a ton of addresses of people trying to get free stuff. What we want to do is give the people who post most on our facebook wall a better chance of winning.

So I am trying to set something up (I'm guessing using Graphs API/FQL) that will pull the name of the person who posted to our wall or commented on one of our posts. If I can get a list like this, I have enough php/mysql experience that I can create the code to compare the name with the database and weight their entry.

Does anyone have a simple explanation on the code to pull just the names of the people who posted each time?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FQL you can get the ids of those who posted on your page wall:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id
FROM stream
WHERE source_id = "PAGE_ID"
```

and those who commented on posts:

```
SELECT post_id, fromid
FROM comment
WHERE post_id = "POST_ID"
```

You also should be able to combine them:

```
SELECT post_id, fromid
FROM comment
WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id
                  FROM stream
                  WHERE source_id = "PAGE_ID")
```

Once you have the ids you can simply query: https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID and get the name of the user.
If you have too many and don't want to issue a request per one you might want to consider using the [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) option.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give that a shot! I tried to vote you +1, but I don't have a good even reputation yet. Haha. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I know, but if this answers your question you can accept it.

Comment: Perfect. The FQL works perfectly! Although it is only returning 32 and 44 results respectively... Do you know if it is different now that our page is a "timeline"? Or could it be the pagination from facebook? Any hints on how to get all the results from let's say April?

Comment: Both tables have a timestamp column, in the [*comment table*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) you have the *"time"* column, and in the [*stream table*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) you have the *"created_time"*. Add to the queries something like "WHERE.. AND time < 1335854863" (may 1st timestamp)